# Why debug key works in Firebase but not in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

It has been the first time I uploaded an app with Google Maps to the Play Store, so I made the mistake of not adding a release SHA1 key to the Google Dev Console. The map was not working until I changed the SHA1 key to a release one.

I'm also using Firebase Notifications and I haven't added a release SHA1 key into the Firebase console, but the notifications are still working, why?

Should I leave that key and that's all? Or should I add the release SHA1 key also to the Firebase console, download the new generated `google-services.json` and then update the app in Google Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SHA1 is not a mandatory requirement when using Firebase in your app, however, it is required when you need to (*as per the helper seen in the Firebase Console*):

> Used to create an OAuth 2 client and API key for your app.

Where the [OAuth 2 Client](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) is used for authentication and authorization so that you can use some Google APIs.

However, if you're only going to use FCM/Notifications, there is no such need for it.

Comment: I ended up adding the signed SHA1 key to Firebase anyway. Good to know that it's not mandatory for FCM though, that's why the unsigned SHA1 key worked too I guess.